# Serverspec doesn't check package version correctly

Tags: ruby, linux, rspec, devops, serverspec

I have a problem with serverspec. I'm trying to check installed package version on ubuntu.

I use this code:

```
describe 'java packages' do
  it 'package openjdk-9-jre should be installed with the correct version' do
    expect(package('openjdk-9-jre')).to be_installed.with_version('9~b114-0ubuntu1')
  end
end
```

Serverspec run dpkg-query command to check package but escapes tilda character and it doesn't work.
serverspec runs:

```
dpkg-query -f '${Status} ${Version}' -W openjdk-9-jre | grep -E '^(install|hold) ok installed 9\\~b114-0ubuntu1$'
```

instead of

```
dpkg-query -f '${Status} ${Version}' -W openjdk-9-jre | grep -E '^(install|hold) ok installed 9~b114-0ubuntu1$'
```

How can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is here: https://github.com/mizzy/specinfra/blob/92ccc19714ead956589127c40e3cd65faf38cb8b/lib/specinfra/command/debian/base/package.rb#L6.

Specinfra is escaping the characters in the `with_version` chain as `#{Regexp.escape(escape(version))}` instead of `#{Regexp.escape(version))`. This would require a PR to Specinfra to fix due to the Specinfra/Serverspec contribution policy. I can put this on my list of things to do and notify you when finished, since I keep an up-to-date Specinfra fork around and am a contributor to both so I know the codebase.

In the meantime, you would have to do a `command` matcher workaround.

```
describe 'java packages' do
  it 'package openjdk-9-jre should be installed with the correct version' do
    describe command("dpkg-query -f '${Status} ${Version}' -W openjdk-9-jre") do
      its(:stdout) { is_expected.to match('^(install|hold) ok installed 9\~b114\-0ubuntu1$') }
    end
  end
end
```

Specinfra PR: https://github.com/mizzy/specinfra/pull/608

Comment: Good, thanks It will be grat if this will be fixed. :)

Comment: It looks like this was fixed in https://github.com/mizzy/serverspec/pull/316/files in ServerSpec and appears to be working for me. Not sure if it's possible to do a `>=` or if it only supports > or <.

Comment: @dragon788 Please note the link in the answer to the PR where I fixed it.

Comment: Aha, I knew I saw it somewhere! It also works with `cmp` in InSpec. It's a shame that fuzzy versions aren't fully supported in all the Chef package resources yet.